# How to enable "packet forwarding" in OS X

Tags: macos, tcpip, forwarding, packet

How is it possible to enable packet forwarding in Mac OS X?

Google gives me tons of hints for Windows and Linux but not for OS X.

Answer (score 12):

You may enable packet forwarding by entering `sudo sysctl -w net.inet.ip.forwarding=1` into the Terminal.